# different tools return different location for specific IP

Tags: ip, whois

I have this IP address:98.114.205.102, which I'd like to locate. While **ip2location.com** and **ipinfo.io** state it is in Pennsylvania running **whois** 98.114.205.102 on my ubuntu terminal returns that it is in Ashburn. I also know, that the correct answer is in Pennsylvania.

So,what could be the problem with whois?

Answer (score 1):

There's no "problem" with whois, it's not supposed to be used for geolocation purposes. The details it reports relate to the owner or operator of the IP address, not the physical location of the IP. For example, all comcast IPs have comcast HQ in their whois information:

```
$ whois -h whois.radb.net 98.248.33.195
route:      98.192.0.0/10
descr:      Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.
            1800 Bishops Gate Blvd
            Mt Laurel, NJ  08054
origin:     AS7922
mnt-by:     MAINT-AS7922
changed:    tony_tauber@spam-free.cable.comcast.com 20090714
source:     RADB
```

But that IP is actually in Mountain View, CA, as you can see from http://ipinfo.io:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/98.248.33.195
{
  "ip": "98.248.33.195",
  "hostname": "c-98-248-33-195.hsd1.ca.comcast.net",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.3860,-122.0838",
  "org": "AS7922 Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.",
  "postal": "94040"
}
```

It's the same with your example IP 98.114.205.102, which is owned by Verizon. The Verizon Enterprise address listed on http://www.verizonenterprise.com/industry/public_sector/ exactly matches that returned in the whois lookup.